# Prefered way to fork / start subprocesses in Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, fork

Let's say I have this scenario:

```
Scenario: Test LDAP access
Given that the LDAP dummy server is started
And the LDAP query is executed
...
```

I wish to start a LDAP server in that step. In my case, I use `ruby-ldapserver`, so I could, in theory, do this in my step:

```
args = { ... }
@ldap_pid = fork do
   redirect_stdout_stderr_to_logfile()
   wait_for_ldap_requests(args)
   exit   # avoid messing with Cucumber/web driver cleanup
end

...

After do
 if @ldap_pid
   Process.kill("HUP", @ldap_pid)
   Process.wait @ldap_pid
 end
```

end

A totally different approach:

```
system("some_script_that_starts_ldap_dummy < #{input} >#{tmpfile} 2>&1 &")
```

This certainly works but is rather unelegant (starting a ruby program from inside ruby - unnecessary process creation, and I need to set up the input parameters for that subprogram as well).

All that said, I'm not too altogether about either approach (the "warm fuzzy feeling" is not there).

What is your standard approach to these things? *Is* there one to speak of? Does Cucumber bring something to the table that could support me here? Should I run something to tell Cucumber that it has forked and should handle itself like a child process?

**Edit:** actually, when playing around with the `fork` approach, I did not notice any problems with the DB at all. I *did* notice that if I kill the child with  `SIGINT`, it *will* break the web driver (Poltergeist / PhantomJS) in my case. A functioning workaround for this is to send a `SIGHUP`, handle it in the child by shutting down gracefully (if needed) but *not* calling`exit`; and then, after a few seconds a `SIGKILL` (which denies the child any chance to close down any protocols and just rips it away). Not nice... and not free of race conditions, say if the CI server should be under load.

Comment: I don't think cucumber really covers this level of implementation detail, nor does it handle the db cleanup itself.

Comment: See edit, @maxple.